# Есть ли возможность при запуске .bat файла установить факт был ли он запущен вручную или автоматически(Task sheduler)?

Tags: windows, bat, автоматизация, task, users

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

**Моя ситация:** С помощью Task Sheduler ежедневно запускается определенный .bat файл. Иногда есть потребность запускать его вручную.

**Моя задача:** При ручном запуске от Юзера, после прохождения команд оставить консоль открытую (Pause) чтобы прочитать логи. При этом после запуска с помощью Task Sheduler процесс должен терминироваться без Паузы. %USERNAME% не подходит, так как TS запускает бптник от того же пользователя, что и запускает его вручную.

Есть ли возможность определить запускает батник Task Sheduler?
Может можно терминировать программу другим способом? 
Например через минуту после того как она дойдет до конца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Настройте запуск этого самого батника с параметром. В самом батнике проверяйте параметр:

```
if "%1"=="" pause
```

или вот так:

```
if not "%1"=="nopause" pause
```

Вариант 2. Научите пользователя запускать батник не двойным кликом - а как полагается, из командной строки. Командная строка не закрывается просто так.

Вариант 3. Научите пользователя запускать батник используя FAR Manager. Там можно посмотреть консольный вывод скрыв панели (Ctrl+O)

---

Но самым "красивым" способом я считаю создание отдельного ярлыка для батника. В этом ярлыке настраивается запуск файла через cmd с ключом /k. Ключ /k означает "выполнить команду и не закрывать консоль":

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Мне нравитсья ваш последний вариант. Но к сожалению, я не могу найти нужной информации как это сделать.
Вариант 2 могу перейнять в свою практику, но для меня, к сожалению, не будет работать, потмоу что программой возможжно будут пользоваться юзеры без технических знаний. Вариант 1 взял на заметку, спасибо

Comment: @S.G. вы не можете сделать что? Создать ярлык на файл?!

Comment: @S.G. просто перетащите ваш файл куда надо зажав Ctrl и ПКМ. В меню выберите "Создать ярлык(и)". А потом зайдите в свойства ярлыка и отредактируйте как на скриншоте.

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня блочаться картинки на рабочем компе. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> Есть ли возможность определить запускает батник Task Sheduler?

В принципе, эту информацию можно вытащить (см. комментарий @avp к посту)

[image: запущенный процесс из-под шедулера]

Видно, что можно поискать родителя и сравнить с svchost.exe.

Однако, мне кажется, что лучше решить вашу задачу другим способом.

Можно передавать при запуске из таск шедулера дополнительный параметр, который опускать при ручном запуске.

Когда батник получит управление -- проверить, с каким параметром был вызван.

Если вручную -- запустить дополнительную команду (паузу).

По-моему весьма тривиальный и логичный воркэраунд.

Comment: Пара минут в гугления вывела на `(gwmi win32_process -Filter "processid='$pid'").parentprocessid` -- это видимо означает, что данные о родителе процесса в винде есть. Осталось идентифицировать  родителя с Task Sheduler

Comment: @avp Да, похоже вы правы. Попробовал запустить шедулер, посмотрел, что покажет process explorer. Однако я согласен с Майоровым -- намного проще обойтись дополнительным параметром.

Comment: Конечно проще (вы об этом параметре тоже писали). Я винду не знаю, но стало интересно, неужели в ней нет  PPID?

Answer (score -1):

В Task Scheduler запускать VbScript, который будет запускать батник и после отработки процесса завершать его.

Терминировать процесс можно так.

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("taskkill /IM iexplore.exe", 0);
```

Comment: Брррррррррррррр